# One registry key for many products not deleted on uninstall

Tags: wix, registry

My company has many products, we want to create a registry key `Software\$(var.Manufacturer)`that will have all of our products if our customers have installed more than one (which is likely) I then want to have a secondary key for each of our products which get removed on uninstall but the main one does not. I have tried to achieve this like below but my main key gets deleted so all of my other products also get deleted from the registry. I know this is trivial but I cannot find an answer.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="Registry" Guid="*" MultiInstance="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Default" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="*" MultiInstance="yes" >
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\[PRODUCTNAME]" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Installed" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ProductName" Value="[PRODUCTNAME]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

EDIT: I have got my registry keys to stay using the following code. However they only all delete wen all products are deleted, not one by one as they need to.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="Registry" Guid="FF75CA48-27DE-430E-B78F-A1DC9468D699" Permanent="yes" Shared="yes" Win64="$(var.Win64)">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Default" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="D94FA576-970F-4503-B6C6-BA6FBEF8A60A" Win64="$(var.Win64)" >
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\[PRODUCTNAME]" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Installed" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ProductName" Value="[PRODUCTNAME]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guid="*" probably disn't going to work well for you here.  You need to use a static GUID ( probably in a fragment so it can be shared by multiple products )  with the Shared attribute set to true.   You can do it the way you are doing it for the subkeys.

This way MSI will properly reference count the parent key and know when to delete it.

Comment: `<Component Id="Registry" Guid="FF75CA48-27DE-430E-B78F-A1DC9468D699" MultiInstance="yes" Permanent="yes" Shared="yes">` That keeps the main registry key but now my secondary keys for the products are not getting deleted when they are uninstalled. Do i need to add anything? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to set the MultiInstance attribute.  Also the component for the secondary keys should all have unique guids.  Becareful using [PRODUCTNAME] in the reqistry path. That might cause problems during servicing.  Otherwise I need to look at your built MSI's and installation logs to give more detailed troubleshooting.

Comment: I took the `MultiInstance` out, i thought that was necessary for transforms. Also have used static GUID and the result is that if there is more than one product they all stay until the last one is removed. I will post my code just incase I am missing something trivial.

Comment: It's synatical sugar but you have to understand how it works. And I have to understand what you are really doing to make sure I don't give bad advice. :)  Are you doing multiple instances of the same product or do you have different products (1 instance each) that just happen to have a shared component here and there?

Comment: Hey, Sorry no I have multiple different products that I would like to be under the same registry key such as `Software\$(var.Manufacturer)` and as each product is installed i would like it added to this key and subsequently deleted when uninstalled. Thanks